# In Java, how do I make variables change with each method call?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that does manual division for whole numbers and prints out the quotient and remainder. I know Java can't change primitives so I would have to use a return type, but I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate it. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Division
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int quo;
    private int a;

    public Division() {
        x = 50; //these two are just temporary for testing
        y = 5;
        quo = 0;
    }

    public void divide() {
        a = (x-y);
        quo++;
    }

    public void checkComplete() {
        if(a > y) {
            this.divide();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Quotient: " + quo);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Division math = new Division();
        math.divide();
        math.checkComplete();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have the variable a change to the output in method divide for future method calls. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is this supposed to do, and why do you call divide() in checkComplete? Every time you call `divide()` `quo` is increased by one. Why?

Comment: Are you trying to write a recursive method?  How does `a = (x - y); quo++';` compute the quotient?  I can see that it might within a for loop (or a recursive call), but I'm not totally sure I would call that "manual division", what are you going to do when you try and divide 1 billion by 2?

Comment: Java CAN change primitives, what did you mean?

Comment: @DWilches I'm assuming the OP referring to the fact that Java is pass-by-value.  I took it to mean that the OP would like to change the values of the parameters in a method call but realizes they cannot do that.

Comment: A method cannot change the value of a _parameter_ that you pass to the method, since Java is "pass-by-value".  However, `a` is an instance field, not a parameter, and the method can change it.  However, if you want a method that changes a value, I don't think it's a good idea to make it an instance field just so you can change it.  Looking at your code, however, I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the division you have to call your `divide` method several times until `a < y` ...

Looking at the code, I see you have this:

```
public void checkComplete() {
    if(a > y) {
        this.divide();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Quotient: " + quo);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't you have a `while (a>=y) { ... }` somewhere there ? Maybe instead of that `if` ?